# gatsby stuck develop build on IMAGE_PROCESSING

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

The build process freezes at the moment Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs

```
  System:
    OS: macOS 12.4
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.14.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node
    npm: 8.10.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Safari: 15.5
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^4.14.1 => 4.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-image: ^2.14.1 => 2.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^4.14.0 => 4.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^5.14.0 => 5.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^5.14.0 => 5.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^4.14.1 => 4.15.0
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^5.14.0 => 5.15.0
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^4.14.0 => 4.15.0
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^4.14.0 => 4.15.0

success compile gatsby files - 0.810s
success load gatsby config - 0.045s
success load plugins - 1.157s
success onPreInit - 0.006s
success initialize cache - 0.130s
success copy gatsby files - 0.143s
success Compiling Gatsby Functions - 0.328s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.352s
success createSchemaCustomization - 3.485s
success Checking for changed pages - 0.001s
success source and transform nodes - 0.164s
success building schema - 0.242s
not finished createPages - 75736.903s
not finished Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs - 75716.723s
```

stuck on

```
⠏ createPages
[============================]   37.377 s 309/309 100% Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs
```

Where can I view logs or understand what's going on? it just hangs on this moment, while build is successful, clean does not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the network or using VPN. Most likely, the problem is in the Xiaomi router when connecting via WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by commenting out the source plugin entries in `gatsby-config` until I found the one that was causing the error. It was a directory of JSON files that had objects in arrays. When I changed it from arrays to just JSON objects, it started working again.